# How to resolve reverse match error in django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I cannot understand why this error is popping up:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'updater' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['update/(?P<updating>[0-9]+)$']
[26/Jul/2020 19:05:05] "GET /update/2 HTTP/1.1" 500 127513
```

my urls:

```py
urlpatterns=[   
    path('update/<int:updating>',views.update,name='updater'),
]
```

the html page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
{% load static %}
    <title>NEW PRODUCT</title>
    
</head>
<body>

    <div class="bg-contact2" style="background-image: url('images/bg-01.jpg');">
        <div class="container-contact2">
            <div class="wrap-contact2">
                <form class="contact2-form validate-form" method="post" action="{%url 'updater' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    <span class="contact2-form-title">
                        Provide Product details Below
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate="type is required">
                        <input class="input2" type="text" name="type" value="{{details.product_type}}">
                        <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder="PRODUCT-TYPE"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate = "Name is required">
                        <input class="input2" type="text" name="name" value="{{details.product_name}}">
                        <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder="PRODUCT NAME"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate = "description is required">
                        <textarea class="input2" name="description">{{details.product_description}}</textarea>
                        <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder="PRODUCT DESCRIPTION"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate = "Price is required">
                        <input class="input2" type="number" name="price" value="{{details.product_price}}">
                        <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder="PRICE"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate = "Picture is required">
                        <label >product sample picture</label>
                        <input class="input2" type="file" name="picture">
                        <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder=""></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-contact2-form-btn">
                        <div class="wrap-contact2-form-btn">
                            <div class="contact2-form-bgbtn"></div>
                            <button class="contact2-form-btn">
                                Update Product Listing
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

my views:

```py
def update (request,updating):
    if request.method=='POST':
        product_details=product_info.objects.get(id=updating)
        product_details.product_type=request.POST.get('type')
        product_details.product_name=request.POST.get('name')
        product_details.product_description=request.POST.get('description')
        product_details.product_price=request.POST.get('price')
        if (len(request.FILES) != 0):
            image = request.FILES['picture']
            product_details.product_pic = image
        product_details.save()
        alldetails = product_info.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'adminside/editingpage.html', {'editing_details': alldetails})
    else:
        product_details = product_info.objects.get(id=updating)
        return render(request,'adminside/updating.html',{'details':product_details})
def update (request,updating) :
    if request.method=='POST' :
        product_details=product_info.objects.get(id=updating)
        product_details.product_type=request.POST.get('type')
        product_details.product_name=request.POST.get('name')
        product_details.product_description=request.POST.get('description')
        product_details.product_price=request.POST.get('price')
        if (len(request.FILES) != 0):
            image = request.FILES['picture']
            product_details.product_pic = image
        product_details.save()
        alldetails = product_info.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'adminside/editingpage.html', {'editing_details': alldetails})
    else:
        product_details = product_info.objects.get(id=updating)
        return render(request,'adminside/updating.html',{'details':product_details})
def update (request,updating):
    if request.method=='POST':
        product_details=product_info.objects.get(id=updating)
        product_details.product_type=request.POST.get('type')
        product_details.product_name=request.POST.get('name')
        product_details.product_description=request.POST.get('description')
        product_details.product_price=request.POST.get('price')
        if (len(request.FILES) != 0):
            image = request.FILES['picture']
            product_details.product_pic = image
        product_details.save()
        alldetails = product_info.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'adminside/editingpage.html', {'editing_details': alldetails})
    else:
        product_details = product_info.objects.get(id=updating)
        return render(request,'adminside/updating.html',{'details':product_details})
```

I think it has something to do with passing the id of the product in the url, but I'm not sure about how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

you have not put any argument in the url you have to put argument in the form action for updating like this

```
<form class="contact2-form validate-form" method="post" action="{%url 'updater' updating='ANYVALUE' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

because you haven't specify any value your url is not matching

Answer (score 0):

This urlpattern `update/` takes an `int` route parameter

```
path('update/<int:updating>',views.update,name='updater'),
```

In your template, you're trying to reverse `updater` with no included argument. So it's trying to reverse to a urlpattern of `update/` which it can't find because you only have a path for `update/<int:updating>`

```
{%url 'updater' %}
```

You will need to change it to the following as you gave the `context` object the name `details` and you can access

```
{%url 'updater' details.id %}
```